# Why is that inline-block parent of an no-wrap ellipsis child always seems to take place for complete text?

Tags: html, css, layout

Please check this example [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/xesazi/1/edit?html,css,output), here we have simple layout we have a child which have too long text and we need to make it `no-wrap` `ellipsis` to avoid breaking of layout but parent seems to occupy the width more then (probably equal to the text) the actual displayed text.

Below is the code

**HTML**

```
<div class="title-logo-container" >
 <span class="logo">
   <a href="/" >                
        <img src="" alt="LOGO IMAGE">
   </a>

</span>
<p class="page-title" s>
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.title-logo-container {
  border: solid 1px #f00;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}

.logo {
    margin: 1.375em 1.5625em 15px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 5.625em;
    z-index: 103;
    display: inline-block;
}

.page-title {
    max-width:40%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Please suggest.

Expected Output 
[image]

Comment: what is the expected output, can u show as image representation?

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to line-boxes...but you'd have to dig into the spec.

Comment: @G.L.P Expected output will be simply parent being equal to child element

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying a percentage max-width for an inline-block that is a child of a float that doesn't have an explicit width. This results in [undefined behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths) because there is a circular dependency between the parent (float) width and the child (inline-block) width.

The apparent browser behavior is that the float is shrink-wrapped to the size of its contents — just enough to contain the content in one line — first, so that it has a size on which the inline-block can then base its 40% max-width. The inline-block then clips its content via `overflow: hidden`. The size of the float is not computed again.

Comment: I think you are correct. but then what will be the solution the problem when I need to add a  one more inline-block div next to the parent div  of variable width. ?

Comment: any idea on the solution ?

Comment: @Champ: There isn't one. You are depending on behavior that cannot possibly be defined.

Answer (score 0):

As BoltClock said, I dont think here inline-block works for this situation, you can try table like this:
 **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t0fkv263/3/)**

```
.title-logo-container {
  clear: both;
  border: solid 1px #f00;
  background: green;
  display: table-cell;
}

.logo {
  margin: 1.375em 1.5625em 15px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 5.625em;
  z-index: 103;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #ff0;
}

.page-title {
  max-width: 40%;
  display: table-cell;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Hope this helps you !

Comment: Demo doesn't  make ".page-title" ellipsis. Please verify.

Answer (score 0):

Check out below solution:

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/daozhu3f/)**

CSS:

```
.title-logo-container {
  border: solid 1px #f00;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

.logo {
    margin: 1.375em 1.5625em 15px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 103;
    display: inline-block;
}

.page-title {
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: you demo dose not work. Please verify on full screen. Thanks